# NSXMLParser delegate methods not working in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

NSXMLParser delegate methods are not called in iOS6 but is is working fine in iOS5. This is how i called my parser

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //Set delegate
    xmlParser.delegate=self;

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    [xmlParser release];
```

Comment: i have called all the delegate methods. I have given only the piece of code to show how i init the parser.